# Is there a way to access a string as a filehandle in php?

Tags: php, csv, filehandle

I'm on a server where I'm limited to PHP 5.2.6 which means str_getcsv is not available to me. I'm using, instead fgetcsv which requires "A valid file pointer to a file successfully opened by fopen(), popen(), or fsockopen()." to operate on.

My question is this: is there a way to access a string as a file handle?

My other option is to write the string out to a text file and then access it via `fopen()` and then use `fgetcsv`, but I'm hoping there's a way to do this directly, like in perl.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you take a look in the user notes on the manual page for [`str_getcsv`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), you'll find [this note from daniel](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#88311), which proposes this function *(quoting)* :

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('str_getcsv')) {
    function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ",", $enclosure = '"', $escape = "\\") {
        $fiveMBs = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        $fp = fopen("php://temp/maxmemory:$fiveMBs", 'r+');
        fputs($fp, $input);
        rewind($fp);

        $data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, $delimiter, $enclosure); //  $escape only got added in 5.3.0

        fclose($fp);
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

It seems to be doing exactly what you asked for : it uses a stream, which points to a temporary filehandle in memory, to use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) on it.

See [PHP input/output streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) for the documentation about, amongst others, the `php://temp` stream wrapper.

*Of course, you should test that it works OK for you -- but, at least, this should give you an idea of how to achieve this ;-)*

Comment: I'd upvote this twice if could - you always seem to have spot on answers. I need to read the user notes more often.

Comment: Thanks :-) ;;; The users notes quite often bring some interesting piece of information :-) *(Well, if one of use has a problem, chances are someone else already had that same problem before ^^ )*

Comment: Its interesting to note, after doing some reading, you can just use `php://memory` - the only advantage to `php://temp` is after the file exceeds the designated size, it will write to disc; if you're under that file size it stays entirely in memory.

Comment: @Erik : I have to admit I've never been in a situation where I hit that size limit -- but thanks for the note : it's definitly good to know !

Comment: I've often seen `fopen("php://output", 'r+');` used, but your solution is better because it does not interfere with the main output.

Answer (score 10):

I'm horrified that no one has answered this solution:

```
<?php

$string = "I tried, honestly!";
$fp     = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $string,'r');

echo stream_get_contents($fp);

#fputcsv($fp, .......);

?>
```

And memory hungry perfect solution:

```
<?php

class StringStream
{
    private   $Variable = NULL;
    protected $fp       = 0;

    final public function __construct(&$String, $Mode = 'r')
    {
        $this->$Variable = &$String;

        switch($Mode)
        {
            case 'r':
            case 'r+':
                $this->fp = fopen('php://memory','r+');
                fwrite($this->fp, @strval($String));
                rewind($this->fp);
                break;

            case 'a':
            case 'a+':
                $this->fp = fopen('php://memory','r+');
                fwrite($this->fp, @strval($String));
                break;

            default:
                $this->fp = fopen('php://memory',$Mode);
        }
    }

    final public function flush()
    {
        # Update variable
        $this->Variable = stream_get_contents($this->fp);
    }

    final public function __destruct()
    {
        # Update variable on destruction;
        $this->Variable = stream_get_contents($this->fp);
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        switch($name)
        {
            case 'fp': return $fp;
            default:   trigger error('Undefined property: ('.$name.').');
        }

        return NULL;
    }
}

$string = 'Some bad-ass string';
$stream = new StringStream($string);

echo stream_get_contents($stream->fp);
#fputcsv($stream->fp, .......);
```

?>

Comment: In your first `data://` approach, the provided `$string` should be percent encoded before being fed into `data://`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php#100979.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your general question, yes you can treat a variable as a file stream.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

The following is a copy and paste from a few different comments on the PHP manual (so I cannot vouch for how production ready it is):

```
<?php
class VariableStream {
    private $position;
    private $varname;
    public function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path) {
        $url = parse_url($path);
        $this->varname = $url["host"];
        $this->position = 0;
        return true;
    }
    public function stream_read($count) {
        $p=&$this->position;
        $ret = substr($GLOBALS[$this->varname], $p, $count);
        $p += strlen($ret);
        return $ret;
    }
    public function stream_write($data){
        $v=&$GLOBALS[$this->varname];
        $l=strlen($data);
        $p=&$this->position;
        $v = substr($v, 0, $p) . $data . substr($v, $p += $l);
        return $l;
    }
    public function stream_tell() {
        return $this->position;
    }
    public function stream_eof() {
        return $this->position >= strlen($GLOBALS[$this->varname]);
    }
    public function stream_seek($offset, $whence) {
        $l=strlen(&$GLOBALS[$this->varname]);
        $p=&$this->position;
        switch ($whence) {
            case SEEK_SET: $newPos = $offset; break;
            case SEEK_CUR: $newPos = $p + $offset; break;
            case SEEK_END: $newPos = $l + $offset; break;
            default: return false;
        }
        $ret = ($newPos >=0 && $newPos <=$l);
        if ($ret) $p=$newPos;
        return $ret;
    }
}

stream_wrapper_register("var", "VariableStream");
$csv = "foo,bar\ntest,1,2,3\n";

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("var://csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Of course, for your particular example, there are simpler stream methods that can be used.

Comment: Nice answer, and technically the cleanest solution. Writing to a file first just seems wrong!

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to use a global variable. why don't you use context to add the ability to use any variable not just globals.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream handles such as [php://memory](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) to achieve what you're after.  Just open, fwrite, rewind, and you should be able to use fgetcsv.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, that is not possible. You cannot treat a string as if it's a stream from a file. You would indeed have to first write the string to a file, and then open said file using `fopen`.

And now for the obvious part, have you considered upgrading?

Comment: Client's server, not my server. Shared hosting environment, yadda yadda yadda ... I'm running the latest version on MY box, ofc.

Comment: :) Didn't know about those, thanks for the link! I suppose you learn something new every day. Obviously though upgrading would still be the best solution.