# how to use fgetcsv with strings

Tags: php, csv

How to use `fgetcsv` where the input is a string and not a resource?

How to convert the string into a resource?

`fgetcsv` expects a file handle resource

```
$str = "1981;2992;19191\n392;488;299\n"some\ntext";199;222";
$array = fgetcsv($str);
```

Can not use `str_getcsv` because then I have to split the string by `\n` before `str_getcsv`.. If some of the fields contains `\n` then the output will be incorrect

Comment: Can you replace `\n` with `;` and then use `str_getcsv()` with `;` as your delimiter?

Comment: no.. not possible.. the output will be incorrect

Comment: the `\n` is a part of the field..

Comment: Did you try explode(';',$str); as a workaround?

Comment: can you explain what your expected output will be ? do you want the endlines as part of the field they are near or as actual end lines? say in your example `"1981;2992;19191\n392;488;299\n"some\ntext";199;222"` will translate into `$result=["1981","2992","19191\n392",etc]` or `$result1=["1981","2992","19191"],  $result2 = ["392","488","299",etc]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function, it can parse CSV string into an array.

Update: if you cannot use `str_getcsv` function, try to convert string to stream and use it in `fgetcsv`:

```
$stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fwrite($stream, '1981;2992;19191\n392;488;299');
rewind($stream);
$array = fgetcsv($stream);
```

Comment: @clarkk ok, see my update, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks.. Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
str_getcsv()
```

[str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Since that is not an option here is an answer that might help, or point you in the right direction:

[String to filehandle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2276659/1198563)
 Not sure if that will work for you
Good Luck.